# If every conjugacy class of $C$ is even, then every finite-dimensional representation $V$ of $G$ over $F$ satisfies $V\simeq V^*$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and $F$ a field with $\text{char}(F) \nmid \# G .$ We say that a conjugacy class $C$ of $G$ is *even* if $g \in C$ implies $g^{-1} \in C$.

> Show that if every conjugacy class of $C$ is even, then every
>   finite-dimensional representation $V$ of $G$ over $F$ satisfies $V\simeq V^*$.

Could you please help me with the above problem?

> Now assume that $F$ splits $G$. Show that the number of even conjugacy
>   classes of $G$ equals the number of isomorphism classes of irreducible
>   representations $V$ of $G$ over $F$ satisfying $V \simeq V^*$.

We have "*the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ equals the number of isomorphism classes of irreducible representations $V$ of $G$ over $F$*". Is the second conclusion trivial?

By the way, why it requires "$F$ splits $G$"?

Thanks.

Comment: If $g,g^{-1}$ are in the same conjugacy class, then $\chi(g)=\chi(g^{-1})$ for every character $\chi$. But $\chi(g^{-1})$ is always the complex conjugate of $\chi(g)$, and the only numbers equal to their complex conjugate are real numbers.

Comment: I think "number of conjugacy classes equals number of inequivalent irreducible representations" is highly nontrivial. Was my earlier comment of any use?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments, i still don't know how to prove the second conclusion.

Comment: If we're talking about the same thing, I've said it's highly nontrivial. You'll need a textbook on representation theory to see a proof, and it will be long and involved.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!